# Load aliases from .bashrc file while using sudo

Tags: sudo, alias, bashrc

I have set aliases for a few programs in the `.bashrc` file, and they work fine without `sudo` and they don't with `sudo`.

Is there a way to get those aliases work with `sudo`?

For example:

```
nano text.txt #alias nano='nano -icB' WORKS
sudo nano text.txt #alias does not work
```

**NOTE:** I have tried `sudo -E nano text.txt`, but it didn't work.

I am on [Ubuntu 15.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_15.04_.28Vivid_Vervet.29) (Vivid Vervet).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to duplicate your aliases for the root user, too. By e. g. putting them in `/root/.bashrc`.

Perhaps an easier way is to simply put this in your `.bashrc`:

`alias sudo='sudo '`

The space after `sudo` is important. According to the bash manual:

> If the last character of the alias value is a space or tab character, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Comment: how can `sudo` with a space after it can help?

Comment: Again, please see the updated answer. That's a feature of bash.